# Nexus raw repository vs maven repository

Tags: maven, nexus, raw

What is the advantage of using the Maven repository over using the raw repository if they both have same purpose of storing a file?
We can upload the .jar file to either of the repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, Maven and RAW repositories are not the same.**

Yes, both are used to store files, but the difference is how it stores the files.

For instance, maven also maintain metadata for the artifacts when you group maven repositories (proxy and hosted) together into group repository then the metadata will be aggregated in the group maven repository but it won't happen in RAW repositories.